# Simple print command does not show any output in VS Code Python extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a beginner. I have installed code runner extension already but, whenever I code in VS Studio (python extension). In the output section it shows (shown in image below). But the Python code runs fine in terminal. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the file before.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to mark it as the accepted answer ;)

Comment: Every time I have to save the file before running? cuz every time I move to next line the file becomes Unsaved

Comment: Yes the code of a saved file will be the one executed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to save file and then run it. And it successed.